# Time complexity for iteration over a stack

Tags: stack, time-complexity

I have an array of objects, and I have two stacks i go over the array and for every elemment i push the previous objects (pop from stack 1 and push to stack 2) and then resotre them (pop from stack2  and push to stack 1).

I wonder what time complexting it is - o(n) or o(n^2)

because every stack operation (push pop) is o(1).

```
 for (int i = 0; i < buildingsHeight.Length; i++)
            {
            
                while (!BuildingStack.IsEmpty() && !didWeFoundHigerBuilding)
                {
                   
                    BuildingStackNode buildingInLine = BuildingStack.Pop();
                    
                    helperStack.Push(BuildingStack.Pop());
                }

                // restore data 
                while (!helperStack.IsEmpty())
                {
                    BuildingStack.Push(helperStack.Pop());
                }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I suppose you mean "O" and not little "o" (which has a different meaning)? Secondly, saying something like O(n) doesn't make any sense without defining "n". So what is n?

The code you showed is a bit strange in that you are looping over the array `buildingsHeight` but you are not doing anything with the array within the loop. Anyway, the time complexity of this piece of code depends on *two* parameters: the length of `buildingsHeight` `a` and the number `b` of items in `BuildingStack` (assuming that `helperStack` is initially empty).

The while loops each take `O(b)`, and the for loop iterates `a` times, so the overall complexity is `O(ab)`.